# Attackers on sc.imp.live.com

Tags: network, email, attacks, phishing

"Deceptive site ahead

Attackers on sc.imp.live.com may trick you into doing something dangerous      like installing software or revealing your personal information (for example,   passwords, phone numbers, or credit cards).
Google Safe Browsing recently detected phishing on sc.imp.live.com. Phishing sites pretend to be other websites to trick you.

You can report a detection problem or, if you understand the risks to your security, visit this unsafe site."

I am receiving this message from the first time today, 25/02/2016, after, on google chrome, trying to acess my live mail on "https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/outlook-com/" and on "https://www.hotmail.com". Anyone know anything about it? I need to acess my email but i am afraid. Thanks very much.

SOLVED - Actually today 26/02/2016 at 01:03 i tryed to acess the hotmail again and this message dont appeared, even i did absolutely nothing to solve this problem. Probably was some error from chrome or a phishing attack in the live mail website, anyway, was solved, how was solved i dont know. This topic can be closed.